# Leaflet never loads leaving the screen blank with no errors

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, leaflet

Im trying to build a reactjs app that has a map, I've wanted to use **leaflet** because of its popularity and the fact that its free and open source. I have attempted to use the libraries leaflet an react-leaflet. My latest attempt implements leaflet with react hooks. No matter what approach I try I get the same results which is a blank screen with no errors in the console. if I check the react development tools component bar everything seems to load fine and the map is in the app hierarchy.

1. I have added the stylesheet for leaflet in public/index.html

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css">
   ```
2. Here is my map hook component

   ```
   import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
   import L from 'leaflet';

   function Map() {
     useEffect(() => {
       // create map
       L.map('map', {
         center: [49.8419, 24.0315],
         zoom: 16,
         layers: [
           L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
             attribution:
               '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
           }),
         ]
       });
     }, []);

     return <div id="map"></div>
   }

   export default Map;`
   ```

Comment: Hi. Did you check my answer? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: just seen it there, I had a imported css file and I tried to replace it with that and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set a map height, that is the reason you see nothing:
Change this line:

```
return <div id="map"></div>
```

to:

```
return <div id="map" style={{ height: "100vh" }} />;
```

to cover the whole screen or give the height of your choice
and it should render after that.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-with-useeffect-hook-rq6ds)